# How to sign apk with keytool

Tags: android, keytool

How can I use keytool to sign my apk? I have java8 installed and the android doc examples are with java6.

Means this

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

not works in java8.

Answer (score -2):

Are you doing development with Android Studio or Eclipse IDE for Android development? If that is the case I would recommend to use it instead as it has a very user friendly wizard to generate signed APK which uses the keytool under the covers. You can check this video : [Generate Signed APK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3nfTc6lZYY)

Also check **Signing Your App in Android Studio** over here: [Android Studio Sign APK](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio)